# How to pass a function to pdepe initial condition function

Tags: matlab, global, curve, pde

I have created a function from sets of points using curve fitting toolbox. I used generate code function and generated function called `createFit(a,b)`, where `a` and `b` are sets of points used for interpolation. As a result `createFit` returns my interpolated function.

Now I want to use this function as the `u0` (initial conditions) of my PDE equation (I am using `pdepe` to solve PDE). To do that, in function where I need to establish `u0` I need to invoke a `createFit` function, which is not a problem, I have access to it. A problem is that I cannot pass `a` and `b` as the parameters to this function. I tried to make them global but it did not worked. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

From the [`pdepe` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html):

> [Parameterizing Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) explains how to provide additional parameters to the functions pdefun, icfun, or bcfun, if necessary.

Essentially, use nested functions or anonymous functions to handle extra parameters.